# magic keyboard vs usb mouse 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

Everytime I manage to connect my magic keyboard the mouse looses the ability to click on anything. (But can still move around).

As soon I as enter  `sudo modprobe -r btusb` and deactivate bluetooth and the keyboard the mouse regains the ability to click on windows/buttons etc.

This doesnt occur when I use a wired keyboard.

I'm running on an Dell XPS8900 desktop. The following is some info that might be helpful with regards to bluetooth devices.

```
$ ~ uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
    Linux cono52-XPS-8900 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8] (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1028:06b8]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e
    --
    02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: bcma, wl
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    [    6.220621] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
    [    6.220629] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [    6.220630] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [    6.220631] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [    6.220634] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [    6.639595] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
    [    6.639596] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
    [    6.639597] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
    [    6.639597] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
    [    6.639598] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
    [    6.639599] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
    [    6.639612] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
    [    6.639619] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
    [    6.639619] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
    [    7.444353] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
    [    7.460474] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
    [    7.461382] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
    [    7.836443] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
    [    7.836446] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd not found
    [   19.514696] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [   19.514698] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [   19.514700] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [   33.422102] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    [   33.422106] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    [   33.422110] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
    [  318.937280] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
    [  318.937291] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
    [ 1018.877874] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8806567cc3c0 failed to resubmit (2)
    [ 1026.888614] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
    [ 1026.904526] Bluetooth: hci0: conor-XPS-8900
    [ 1026.905547] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
    [ 1026.905567] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
    [ 1026.905570] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd not found
    [ 1246.109961] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8805d8875000 failed to resubmit (2)
    [ 1250.456936] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
    [ 1250.472966] Bluetooth: hci0: conor-XPS-8900
    [ 1250.473969] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
    [ 1251.192133] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1572
    [ 1251.208155] Bluetooth: hci0: DW1560 Bluetooth 4.0 LE
    [ 1286.635537] input: Cono52's Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:004C:0267.0008/input/input23
    [ 1286.636198] hid-generic 0005:004C:0267.0008: input,hidraw5: BLUETOOTH HID v0.66 Keyboard [Cono52's Keyboard] on c4:8e:8f:fd:0a:62
    [ 1461.091035] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8805f03f36c0 failed to resubmit (2)
    [ 1531.380734] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
    [ 1531.396745] Bluetooth: hci0: cono52-XPS-8900
    [ 1531.397732] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1572
    [ 1532.118689] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1572
    [ 1532.134727] Bluetooth: hci0: DW1560 Bluetooth 4.0 LE
    [ 1541.156209] input: Cono52's Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/0005:004C:0267.000B/input/input26
    [ 1541.157002] hid-generic 0005:004C:0267.000B: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v0.66 Keyboard [Cono52's Keyboard] on c4:8e:8f:fd:0a:62
    [ 1587.021880] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8806567cda80 failed to resubmit (2)
    [    0.167818] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
    [    7.836443] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
    [ 1026.905567] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
    bluetooth             520192  13 bnep,hidp,btbcm,btqca,hci_uart,rfcomm,btintel
```

Answer (score 1):

Looked around a bit more and found a similar fix that managed to solve this problem also.

```
$ wget "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/r2pb41rhx65t9zi/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd"
$ sudo cp BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
$ sudo modprobe -r btusb 
$ sudo modprobe btusb
```

Reboot the computer.

Magic Keyboard can connect and doesnt break clicking/hover events on windows/buttons etc.

Edit*** The above solution doesn't persist and the problem remains...

```
//only momentarily fixes problem
$ sudo modprobe -r btusb 
$ sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: The quick and dirty path to peristance is to put the modprobe commands into 'Startup Applications'